# No object pairs in plist reading data from a server

Tags: objective-c, plist

I am trying to read a plist from a server. I know for a fact that the plist is valid since when I go to the URL i get the plist downloaded and the plist editor shows me my array properly. Now when I use the following code I get now array populated. I see the data is in there. In debugger i see that plistData has value however the array petListArray has no data at all. What is wrong?

```
    - (void)getPetListRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {   
        NSData *plistData = [request responseData];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format = NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0;
        NSArray *petListArray = (NSArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistData 
                                                                         options:(NSPropertyListReadOptions)NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format error:(NSError **)error];


    if(error){

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"GetPetListError"  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"getPettListRequestFinished_new deserialization error: error = %@", error] 
                                                        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    } 
----snip-------
```

Comment: Does error get set to anything?

Comment: nope, I added the code where i am checking the error, it gives no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong type of argument for the `error:` slot of `- NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:`. Try:

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: plistData 
                             options: (NSPropertyListReadOptions) NSPropertyListImmutable
                             format: &format 
                             error: &error]
```

(edited after checking docs)

Comment: Yes, that was a problem, when I tried that now I get the error.. dont know what it means, but work on it now....Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Encountered unknown tag HTML on line 1) UserInfo=0x60283c0 {NSDebugDescription=Encountered unknown tag HTML on line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)}

Comment: ok, i had an error in the URL the data was coming from, the data contained HTML no plist. I corrected the url everything worked. I got side tracked since error was getting no value. Thanks to Dirk to pointing out the error. Once I saw the error, i tracked it down.